# IOS use presentModalViewController to show some controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, message

i use presentModalViewController to show some controller.

A controller://it will show controller of B and receive a message ,when it receive the Message,i want to kown the B is it show or not?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(recvPushMessage:) name:RECV_PUSH_MESSAGE_NOTIFY object:nil];

}
-(void)buttonAction(id)sender{
     B* b = [B alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController*)b];
     [self presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
     //release 
}
-(void)recvPushMessage{
   //i want to kown B is it show or not
   if(b is showing){
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do something for A
   }

}
```

B controller://when B was show ,i do not want call recvPushMessage in A.

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad{

     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(recvPushMessage:) name:RECV_PUSH_MESSAGE_NOTIFY object:nil];

}
-(void)recvPushMessage{

   //do something for B
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is what you are looking for,

```
-(void)recvPushMessage{

   if (self.presentedViewController) { //check if you have this model view controller
      //do something
   }
   else{
      //do something for A
   }
}
```

For version < iOS 5.0, you can use `self.modalViewController`.

**Update:**
For your second question, you can get the `topViewController` of navigation controller and compare it with C. You can use something like `[self.modalViewController topViewController]` to check if it is C and then proceed.

For eg:-

```
if ([[(UINavigationController *)self.modalViewController topViewController] isKindOfClass:[C class]])
```

Comment: presentedViewController must be IOS5.0,how about 4.3

Comment: you might have to use `self.modalViewController` in that version.

Comment: let me try it ,and if B push some controller like "C",and C also receive the message,how can i kown presentedViewController was C in A

Comment: @ACB In his case self.presentedViewController will be UINavigationController. So he need to get root view controller from it & then compare with "b" controller

Comment: @Rahul, Ya saw the question now only. I was assuming that he is displaying B directly. In that case only my first option is valid.